# How should I authenticate a third party's users on my platform?

Tags: authentication, api, standards

I'm having trouble finding implementation ideas / guidance / examples for an 
authentication system that has the following properties:

- Allows a third party to carry out actions on our platform on behalf of a user.
- Allows a user of the third parties application to carry out actions on our platform directly.
- The user always authenticates with the third party.
- The user never directly authenticates with the platform.

I'm looking for a well defined specification to implement, in the same way that 
the OAuth2 spec defines how a resource owner may grant access
resources to a third party.

An example of the type of authentication system I'd like to implement is the 
Braintree API and their use of Client Secret + Transaction Nonces.

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/overview#how-it-works

Comment: if the user never authenticates with the platform, then the "third party", as you describe it, is in fact, your user (and not a 3rd party). It's an agent. User > "3rd party" > your platform.